# 24:43 is this translation correct?

Tags: quran

The portuguese translation (Hayek) for the [verse 43, sura 24](https://quran.com/24/43?translations=20,43) is:

> Porventura, não reparas em como Deus impulsiona as nuvens levemente? Então as junta, e depois as acumula? Não vês a chuva manar do seio delas?, E que Ele envia massas de granizo, com que atinge quem Lhe apraz, e livrando dele quem quer? **Pouco falta para que o resplendor das centelhas lhes ofusque as vistas.**

I want to know your opinion about the last part of the versicle translated to portuguese, translated to english is something like . this:

> Little time so that the brightness of the sparks they will overshadow the views (human vision, a plural in portuguese for vision - caming from two eyes).

The arabic Quran says something about " there's little time for this" like its translated in this verse?

I found the geral english translation poor related to our portuguese translation (maybe because we have a more rich vocabulary), but in this case it differs too much .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an Arabic speaker but this particular verse uses a little bit of complex old Arabic which confuses me at some parts .
I don't blame any of the translators for not being able to capture the full meaning of the verse , so you may want to take that into account for the diversions between the English / Portuguese translations .

**As for your question** , no , there is no mention of time or little time at all here .
And the highlighted part has more the meaning of "The glare of its lightning almost goes away with their sight " [meaning almost takes away their sight , blinds them]

**Note**:I just google translated the bold part in your question and yes , it seems a little farther from the meaning than the English , or rather , the translator has taken more liberty than the English translator , but I think the meaning is still close enough though .

Comment: Thanks for your response."its lightning" refers to the clouds lightning?

Comment: @bcloney I believe so , but again to give you the full picture , in this verse 2 nouns are mentioned , first **the clouds** up until half the verse , then **the mountains lowered from the sky** also presumed to describe cloud formations in the sky when it is particularly very cloudy , it isn't clear to me if "its lightning" refers to the clouds in general "noun 1" or this particular formation of clouds "noun 2" , both are very possible since "noun 2" describes a very specific look of the clouds and that is when it is heavily cloudy and turbulent and naturally this is when lightning strikes .